# How to declaratively deploy a localized datetime field with validation?

Tags: validation, datetime, sharepoint, localization

The following column definition *DOES* work.

```
<Field ID="{F4313C31-C8DD-4917-98A9-0DE886177758}"
     Type="DateTime"
     Name="ExpirationDate"
     DisplayName="Limited until (if necessary)"
     StaticName="ExpirationDate"
     Group="SomeGroup"
     Required="FALSE" 
     Format="DateOnly"
     FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled"
     CalType="0">
<Validation Message="Please select a date in the future.">=[Limited until (if necessary)]&gt;TODAY()</Validation>
```

But of course I **do not want to use the display name** in my validation formula.
Moving closer to production any display name will be moved a resx file anyway.
And using a resx file I end up with the same error as I encountered before when I was trying to use the **internal field name** instead of the display name.

The error is: ***The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or update the formula to reference only this column.***

This is what SharePoint does itself when creating a column via the UI:

```
<Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="RS Expiration Date" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateOnly" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{15380d60-50d7-4ce1-b21b-92695f0c0811}" SourceID="{8086fd7d-ca0b-4258-9352-f166615b6159}" StaticName="RSExpDate" Name="RSExpDate" ColName="datetime2" RowOrdinal="0" CalType="0" Version="1">
<Validation Message="Please enter a future date." Script="function(x){return SP.Exp.Calc.valid(SP.Exp.Node.f('GT',[SP.Exp.Node.a(0),SP.Exp.Node.f('TODAY',[])]),x)}">=RSExpDate&gt;TODAY()</Validation>
<ValidationDisplayNames>=[RS Expiration Date]&gt;TODAY()</ValidationDisplayNames>
```

Obviously there's a lot of information in there you won't need.
The interesting part is the validation part. It is using "ValidationDisplayNames" instead of "Validation". Still the latter too does only work with display names.